# Cannot resolve class com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I try to use the library "com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0", but I cannot.

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. I add the dependency: implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0' into build.gradle(:app).
2. I add jcenter(), maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } into build:gradle(Project).
3. I have synced the project.
4. I put the example inside the <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout> label.

[image]

5. I received the error: "Cannot resolve class com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView".

I am using compileSdk 32, minSdk 21
Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

file build.gradle:module

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

File build.gradle:app

```
   plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.socialtravel"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'io.github.florent37:shapeofview:1.4.7'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0'
    implementation('id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0') {
        exclude module: 'unspecified'
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.smarteist:Android-Image-Slider:1.4.0'
}
```

And the activity xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.PostDetailActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView
            android:id="@+id/imageSlider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:sliderAnimationDuration="600"
            app:sliderAutoCycleDirection="back_and_forth"
            app:sliderAutoCycleEnabled="true"
            app:sliderIndicatorAnimationDuration="600"
            app:sliderIndicatorGravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            app:sliderIndicatorMargin="15dp"
            app:sliderIndicatorOrientation="horizontal"
            app:sliderIndicatorPadding="3dp"
            app:sliderIndicatorRadius="2dp"
            app:sliderIndicatorSelectedColor="#5A5A5A"
            app:sliderIndicatorUnselectedColor="#FFF"
            app:sliderScrollTimeInSec="1"
            app:sliderStartAutoCycle="true" />


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have created a new project, I add these three files and I receive the same error: "Could not find com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView"

Comment: There's demo app included in project repo - you can check if your project setup matches.

Comment: Did you gradle sync after changing the build.gradle? Does the sync inform of any errors?

Comment: I have synced after including the dependency, but the result is the same.

Comment: I have done it without success.
I attach the content of my files.

Comment: I imagine that there is something wrong in these files that I have attached in the question. Due to the fact that I have create a new project, I add these three files and I receive the same error: "Could not find com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
The problem was that I was adding the implementation text line in the gradle:app but I should have added it in the setting.gradle.
I hope my answer can help other people who find the same problem.
Regards!